# PHP preg_match_all returns empty arrays

Tags: php, regex

I have this `preg_match_all`:

```
$cash = "hi £240";

preg_match_all("/^£?(([1-9]{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?)|(0\.[1-9]\d)|(0\.0[1-9]))$/", $cash, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

And the print_r returns:

Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) [3] => Array ( ) [4] => Array ( ) [5] => Array ( ) [6] => Array ( ) )

When I tried just preg_match, it didnt work at all, did I miss something?

I am searching the string for GB monetary values.

Comment: Maybe you need to add utf flag? It was `u`?

Comment: Why should it match anything at all? With the use of `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) you specified that the enclosed money expression must be the *whole string*. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cash = "hi £240";
preg_match_all("/£(?P<amount>\d*,?\d*\.?\d*)/",$cash,$match);

print_r($match['amount']);
```

Comment: won't match values with decimals or commas.

Comment: Edited the answer please check it now

Comment: still won't match with commas. Also why would you put `\.*` that would allow ....... for instance. It should be `\.?`

Comment: Changes the answer, @crypticツ Thanks again :)

Comment: `£240,00,0.0.0` should not be match at all, but it returns `240,00` keep trying and testing invalid/valid numbers so that it is as strict a match as OP is doing.